# Javascript: Retrieve Object Property Names

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function that needs to know the property names of an object being passed in, like so:

```
var data = { "key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", etc}
               ^ i want the string value "key1"
```

How do I retrieve the string "key1" from `data`? I know I can set a property dynamically like `data[prop]=value` but i want to know what `prop` is from an object passed in.

If that doesn't make sense I suppose I could try to explain more. Thanks!

I eventually want to do something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++)
{
    var name = data[i].getPropertyName() <--- not a real function
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Before we look at our options, a quick note of the four key things about properties in JavaScript:

1. Objects can have properties of their own, and properties they inherit from their prototype object.
2. Properties can be *enumerable* or *non-enumerable*.
3. Properties can have names that are *strings*, or (as of ES2015/ES6) names that are `Symbol`s.
4. Properties cannot have names that are numbers, like 1. Sometimes we act like they do, as when we're dealing with arrays, but they don't. Standard arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html) (per the spec; JavaScript implementations are allowed to optimize when they can), and the entries in arrays are object properties whose names are strings. So `a = ['x', 'y', 'z']` defines an array with three properties whose names are `"0"`, `"1"`, and `"2"`. When we do `a[0]` to access the first one, the number `0` is converted to a string. (In theory; again, the JavaScript implementation is allowed to optimize.)

All of these properties can be discovered and enumerated (even the non-enumerable ones).
You have several options for doing so:

- A **`for-in` loop** ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)), with or without a [`hasOwnProperty`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.hasownproperty) guard inside the loop to differentiate between "own" and inherited properties. (Does not include properties named with `Symbol`s.) Loops through the *names* of the properties.
- **`Object.keys`** ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.keys) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)) (ES5+), which returns an array of the names of an object's own, enumerable properties. (Does not include properties named with `Symbol`s.)
- **`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`** ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.getownpropertynames) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)) (ES5+), which returns an array of the names of an object's own properties, regardless of whether they're enumerable. (Does not include properties named with `Symbol`s.)
- <s>**`Reflect.enumerate`** ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-reflect.enumerate) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/enumerate)) (ES2015+), which returns an iterator for the names of the enumerable properties of an object, including ones it inherits.  (Does not include properties named with `Symbol`s.)</s> It was removed in ES2016.
- **`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`** ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.getownpropertysymbols) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols)) (ES2015+), which returns an array of the names of an object's own properties named with `Symbol`s, regardless of whether they're enumerable. (Leaves out ones named with strings.)
- **`Reflect.ownKeys`** ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-reflect.ownkeys) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/ownKeys)) (ES2015+), which returns an array of the names of an object's own properties no matter how they're named (`Symbol` or string), and whether they're enumerable or not.

As you can see, most of the operations only include properties whose names are strings, with only `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols` and `Reflect.ownKeys` giving us the ones named with `Symbol`s.

The order of the keys is not defined (not even in ES2015) for `for-in` or `Object.keys`. In ES2015 and above, it *is* defined for the other four, by the [`[[OwnPropertyKeys]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys) and (where applicable) [`[[Enumerate]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-enumerate) operations. (Since ES2015 is still [as of this writing] relatively knew, it's possible not all JavaScript engines correctly implement the order yet.)

Let's look at examples. First, some setup:

```
// Create an object with one "own" property (plus the ones it
// inherits from Object.prototype):
var proto = {
    one: 1
}

// Create an object that uses the above as its prototype
var obj = Object.create(proto);

// Add a couple of enumerable properties
obj.two = 2;
obj.three = 3;

// Add a non-enumerable property (by default, properties created
// with Object.defineProperty are non-enumerable)
Object.defineProperty(obj, "four", {
   value: 4,
   configurable: true,
   writable: true
});
```

*(`Object.create` was added in ES5, but the version of it taking just one argument [as above] can easily be shimmed/polyfilled for obsolete JavaScript engines, like the one in IE8. `Object.defineProperty` was also added in ES5, and cannot be correctly shimmed/polyfilled.)*

Since most of the operations only involve properties named by strings, we're ignoring `Symbol`s for now.

Once the code above runs, we have this in memory (the `*` next to a name indicates it's a non-enumerable property):

```
                                                    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
Object.prototype−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−>| toString*       |−−>(...a function...)
                                                |   | valueOf*        |−−>(...a function...)
                                                |   | hasOwnProperty* |−−>(...a function...)
                                                |   | ...             |
                                                |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                |
                             +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
proto−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−>| [[Prototype]] |−−+
                         |   | one: 1        |
                         |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                         |
      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
obj−−>| [[Prototype]] |−−+
      | two: 2        |
      | three: 3      |
      | four*: 4      |
      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

With that setup, let's look at our options:

#### `for-in`

`for-in` loops through the names of all of an object's properties (including ones it inherits from its prototype) whose names are strings (leaving out any whose names are `Symbol`s).

```
for (var name in obj) {
    // name is the name of each property, so:
    console.log(name + " = " + obj[name]);
}
```

```js
// Create an object with one "own" property (plus the ones it
// inherits from Object.prototype):
var proto = {
    one: 1
}

// Create an object that uses the above as its prototype
var obj = Object.create(proto);

// Add a couple of enumerable properties
obj.two = 2;
obj.three = 3;

// Add a non-enumerable property (by default, properties created
// with Object.defineProperty are non-enumerable)
Object.defineProperty(obj, "four", {
   value: 4,
   configurable: true,
   writable: true
});

for (var name in obj) {
    // name is the name of each property, so:
    console.log(name + " = " + obj[name]);
}
```

With that, we see

```
two = 2
three = 3
one = 1
```

...or similar. The order you see the properties in is not defined, not even in ES2015.

#### `for-in` with a `hasOwnProperty` guard

If we wanted the loop, but ignoring inherited properties, we can add a `hasOwnProperty` check:

```
for (var name in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        console.log(name + " = " + obj[name]);
    }
}
```

```js
// Create an object with one "own" property (plus the ones it
// inherits from Object.prototype):
var proto = {
    one: 1
}

// Create an object that uses the above as its prototype
var obj = Object.create(proto);

// Add a couple of enumerable properties
obj.two = 2;
obj.three = 3;

// Add a non-enumerable property (by default, properties created
// with Object.defineProperty are non-enumerable)
Object.defineProperty(obj, "four", {
   value: 4,
   configurable: true,
   writable: true
});

for (var name in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        console.log(name + " = " + obj[name]);
    }
}
```

With that, we see

```
two = 2
three = 3
```

We don't see `one` because it's inherited.

Since `hasOwnProperty` is a method on the object, in theory it could be overridden with a version that didn't return what we expect:

```
obj.hasOwnProperty = function() {
    return true;
};
```

...which would fool our loop above. That's not usually an issue, but if you want to guard against it, use the one from `Object.prototype` instead:

```
var hasOwn = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
for (var name in obj) {
    if (hasOwn.call(obj, name)) {
        console.log(name + " = " + obj[name]);
    }
}
```

Of course, someone can assign to the `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` property as well, but if they do, a fair number of things are likely to break.

#### `Object.keys` (ES5+, easily shimmed/polyfilled)

`Object.keys` gives us an array of the names of the object's *own, enumerable* properties named with strings. So it doesn't include inherited properties, properties marked non-enumerable, or properties named with `Symbol`s.

```
var propNames = Object.keys(obj);
```

We can then loop over the entries in that array in any of several ways, such as `forEach`:

```
propNames.forEach(function(name) {
    console.log(name + " = " + obj[name]);
});
```

```js
// Create an object with one "own" property (plus the ones it
// inherits from Object.prototype):
var proto = {
    one: 1
}

// Create an object that uses the above as its prototype
var obj = Object.create(proto);

// Add a couple of enumerable properties
obj.two = 2;
obj.three = 3;

// Add a non-enumerable property (by default, properties created
// with Object.defineProperty are non-enumerable)
Object.defineProperty(obj, "four", {
   value: 4,
   configurable: true,
   writable: true
});

var propNames = Object.keys(obj);
propNames.forEach(function(name) {
    console.log(name + " = " + obj[name]);
});
```

With our sample setup, that gives us:

```
two = 2
three = 3
```

The order of the names in the array is not defined by the specification, not even in ES2015.

#### `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` (ES5+)

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames` returns an array of the names of the object's own properties named with strings, whether enumerable or not. It leaves out properties named with `Symbol`s.

```
var propNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
propNames.forEach(function(name) {
    console.log(name + " = " + obj[name]);
});
```

```js
// Create an object with one "own" property (plus the ones it
// inherits from Object.prototype):
var proto = {
    one: 1
}

// Create an object that uses the above as its prototype
var obj = Object.create(proto);

// Add a couple of enumerable properties
obj.two = 2;
obj.three = 3;

// Add a non-enumerable property (by default, properties created
// with Object.defineProperty are non-enumerable)
Object.defineProperty(obj, "four", {
   value: 4,
   configurable: true,
   writable: true
});

var propNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
propNames.forEach(function(name) {
    console.log(name + " = " + obj[name]);
});
```

With our sample setup, that gives us:

```
two = 2
three = 3
four = 4
```

The order of the names in the array is defined by the [`[[OwnPropertyKeys]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys) operation in the specification, which says the order is:

- The property names that qualify as [integer indexes](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object-type), in numeric order.
- The names for other properties, in the order the property was created.

So we get `two`, `three`, `four` because none of those fits the spec's definition of an integer index, and that's the order in which we added the properties. If we added them in a different order, or included ones that qualified as indexes, we'd get different results:

```
var obj2 = {};
obj2.four = 4;
obj2[0] = "zero";
obj2.two = 2;
obj2.three = 3;
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj2).forEach(function(name) {
    console.log(name + " = " + obj2[name]);
});
```

```js
var obj2 = {};
obj2.four = 4;
obj2[0] = "zero";
obj2.two = 2;
obj2.three = 3;
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj2).forEach(function(name) {
    console.log(name + " = " + obj2[name]);
});
```

Gives us:

```
0 = zero
four = 4
two = 2
three = 3
```

`0` was first because although it's a string, it fits the criteria for an integer index. Then we get `four` because it was created first, then `two`, then `three`.

#### <s>`Reflect.enumerate` (ES2015)</s> *Removed in ES2016*

**`Reflect.enumerate` was removed in ES2016.**

<s>`Reflect.enumerate` uses the new *iterator* feature of ES2015. It returns an iterator that will iterate over the names of the string-named enumerable properties of the object, including inherited ones, skipping ones named with `Symbol` or that aren't enumerable. First it visits the "own" properties (in the order defined by `[[OwnPropertyKeys]]`, and then inherited properties (unless they've been hidden by "own" properties).</s>

We can use the new `for-of` loop to loop over them:

```
for (let name of Reflect.enumerate(obj)) {
    console.log(name + " = " + obj[name]);
}
```

With our setup, that gives us:

```
two = 2
three = 3
one = 1
```

`one` is at the end because it's inherited, and "own" properties come first.

Note: Again, since ES2015 is relatively new as of this writing, some JavaScript engines may not implement the `Reflect` object yet.

#### `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols` (ES2015+)

`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols` returns an array of an object's own properties named with `Symbol`s, regardless of whether they're enumerable. (Leaves out ones named with strings.) We'll need a different setup to try this, since we didn't include `Symbol`-named properties in our main setup. Since inherited properties are ignored, we'll keep it simple:

```
var obj3 = {};
obj3[Symbol("x")] = "ecks";
obj3[1] = "one";
obj3[Symbol("y")] = "why";
obj3.z = "zee";
Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj3).forEach(function(symbol) {
    console.log(symbol.toString() + " = " + obj3[symbol]);
});
```

```js
var obj3 = {};
obj3[Symbol("x")] = "ecks";
obj3[1] = "one";
obj3[Symbol("y")] = "why";
obj3.z = "zee";
Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj3).forEach(function(symbol) {
    console.log(symbol.toString() + " = " + obj3[symbol]);
});
```

Output:

```
Symbol(x) = ecks
Symbol(y) = why
```

`z` wasn't listed because it has a string name, not a `Symbol` name. `Symbol(x)` was first because it was created first.

There's a lot more to `Symbols` than shown here, but as you can see, if we give a symbol a name, we can use `toString` to get back `Symbol(the name here)` as a string. Interesting, we have to call `toString` *explicitly* (`thesymbol.toString()`) or use `String(theSymbol`); the `+` operator will not do it for us when appending a symbol to a string.

#### `Reflect.ownKeys` (ES2015+)

`Reflect.ownKeys` returns an array of an object's own properties no matter how they're named (`Symbol` or string), and whether they're enumerable or not. It ignores inherited properties:

```
var obj3 = {};
obj3[Symbol("x")] = "ecks";
obj3[1] = "one"
obj3[Symbol("y")] = "why";
obj3.z = "zee";
Reflect.ownKeys(obj3).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key.toString() + " = " + obj3[key]);
});
```

```js
var obj3 = {};
obj3[Symbol("x")] = "ecks";
obj3[1] = "one"
obj3[Symbol("y")] = "why";
obj3.z = "zee";
Reflect.ownKeys(obj3).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key.toString() + " = " + obj3[key]);
});
```

Output:

```
1 = one
z = zee
Symbol(x) = ecks
Symbol(y) = why
```

Note the order, which is defined by `[[OwnPropertyKeys]]`: `1` was first because it's a string that qualifies as an integer index. `z` was next because it's a string-named property. Then we have the `Symbol`-named properties, in the order in which they were created.

Answer (score 6):

```
var data = { "key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}; //etc

for (var prop in data) {
  var propName = prop;
  var propVal = data[prop];
  // do something with your new variables
}
```

Yeah, it's that simple.

Comment: I get a "TypeError: object is not a function" error while trying the same code. Has something changed?

Comment: @kurious: Make sure you only select the code in the gray box. I just tried it and some text ("down vote") miraculously appeared before the first variable declaration (even though there are no down votes on this answer. Any extraneous text *will* cause TypeErrors or "undefined" errors.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by above answers I wondered how to list ALL properties of any object (both emumerable and not) up the inheritance chain.
This function seems sufficient.

```
var allPropNames = [];

function digAllPropsOut (ob){
    var propNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(ob);
    propNames.forEach(function(name) {
        allPropNames.push(name);
    });
    // allPropNames.push('\n');
    ob = Object.getPrototypeOf(ob);
    if (ob)
        digAllPropsOut(ob);
}
```

Comment: You Must replace getOwnPropertyNames by Reflect!
because it not really outputing "all" types (do not forget Symbol from es6)
It will considers all kinds of keys and return both (getOwnProperty* Names/Symbols)
---> Reflect.ownKeys(ob);